# Set of vectors to span.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a set of vectors that span the subspace $W$ of $V$:

1) $V = P^3(\mathbb{R})$ (polynomial degree 3)  $W = \{p|p(1) = p(3) = 0\}$

2) $V = \text{span}(\{\sin x, \cos x, \sin 2x, \cos 2x\})$ contained in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$,
   $W = \{f \in V| f(\pi/4) = 0\text{ and }f'(\pi/4) = 0\}$

My problem isn't really in the technique of what to do, but more so how to set up. Specifically with 1) what is it asking interms of how to set up the equations?

Answer (score 0):

For (1),

Denote the standard basis by $f_n(x) = x^n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

For $p \in P^3(\mathbb{R})$, write $p = \alpha_0 f_0 + \alpha_1 f_1 + \alpha_2 f_2 + \alpha_3 f_3$.

Then $p \in W$ if and only if $p(1) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 0$ and $p(3) = \alpha_0 + 3\alpha_1 + 9\alpha_2 + 27\alpha_3 = 0$.

Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: Let me add a comment: you should eventually find a basis for $W$ consists of 2 independent vectors (i.e. 2 polynomials) and this is more than what you ask since if you add more vectors into the basis, the vectors must be dependent with the basis and it is (certainly) still a spanning set of $W$. Part (2) can be done in a similar manner.

Comment: Yes i know how to proceed from here. It was that interpretation that was throwing me off. Thanks.

Comment: Great. :) You are welcome.